# What is the Canadian Income Tax Day?

Tags: canada, income-tax

In the US, Tax day is April 15th meaning income tax for 2010 must be filed by April 15 2011. Is there an equivalent date for Canadian taxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [April 30th](http://www.taxes.ca/info/dates-deadlines.php) in Canada ([See also](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ll-dts/frms-eng.html)).  Note that if you are getting a refund, rather than paying more taxes, you can be as late as you want without penalty.

Comment: Note that the Province of Québec requires separate provincial income tax filing, though it (usually http://www.revenu.gouv.qc.ca/en/citoyen/impots/dec_courante/produire.aspx) falls on the same date.